# How can I determine what function callq is calling here?

Tags: macos, assembly, x86-64

Just to satisfy my curiosity, I've been running `otool -tV ./MyApp.app/Contents/MacOS/MyApp > out.txt` on various MacOS/X executables, and then looking at the generated assembly-code listings in `out.txt` to see what's in them.

In a lot of places, I see something like this:

```
0000000100bae6fb        callq   0x100bb2dc8 ## symbol stub for: _memcpy
```

... which, with the helpful comment, makes perfect sense; I can tell that this line's purpose is to call the `memcpy()` function, which will be located at address `0x100bb2dc8` in the process's memory-space.

In other locations, however, there are instances of `callq` with no helpful comment, e.g.:

```
000000010056247c        callq   0x11056246d
```

... and in these cases, I don't know how to tell what function is being called.  Is there any way to figure that out?

(I tried looking for the referenced address in `otool`'s output, but AFAICT it is not present there; the address-values at the beginning of each line range from `00000001000061c0` through `0000000100bb014c`, and that range doesn't include address `0x11056246d`)

Comment: 1) Are you sure there isn't an asterisk in there (i.e. `callq   *0x11056246d`)? 2) You can check the load commands using `otool -lV` to see if any of the executable's sections include that address. If so, it may be helpful to dump that section using `otool -V -s <segment> <section>` (although not all sections get formatted usefully).

Comment: @KenThomases There's definitely no asterisk there.  AFAICT the address is not part of any of the address ranges listed in the `otool -lV` output (the ranges listed all start with `000000010xxxxxxxx', and according to their `size` attribute, aren't big enough to get into the `000000011xxxxxxxx` range).  I wonder if this address represents a call into a shared library somehow?

Comment: Are you able to run the app, attach `lldb`, and disassemble that same code? Note that the executable will probably not be loaded at the same address assumed when `otool` disassembles it, because of ASLR. If the code with that `callq` instruction has a symbol name associated with it, you can do `disass -a <symbol>` to see it. Otherwise, you can use the `image list -o` to show the slide offset and then `disass -s 0x000000010056247c-<offset> -c 1` to see that `callq`. That should be sufficient to get `lldb` to show the symbol for that call.

Comment: @KenThomases: A direct near jump/call uses a `rel32` encoding for the branch target, so the absolute target calculated by the disassembler will match any address ranges it prints.  (Because it's calculated from an instruction address in one of those ranges, and ASLR doesn't move sections/segments relative to each other).  Another possibility is that overlapping code or some other obfuscation / complication broke the disassembly (by starting from a byte that execution wouldn't start from), and this "call rel32" is just a sequence of 5 bytes in the middle of something else.

Comment: `0x11056246d - (0x000000010056247c+5)` =  `0x0fffffec`.  That's an interesting coincidence for the rel32 call displacement encoding, makes me wonder if something weird is going on.

Comment: @PeterCordes, my `lldb`suggestion wasn't based on the theory that the relative offsets of the call site to the sections would change. It was based on the theory that the call site might somehow be link-edited at load time, so you'd only see the true referent in a loaded process.